# Send itms: to safari nstead of webview

Tags: iphone

I have the following code:

```
  Webview *web = [[Webview alloc] initWithNibName:@"Webview" bundle:nil];
  [web setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
  [self presentModalViewController:web animated:YES];
  [web loadThisURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]];
  [web release];
```

I'd like to wrap that around an if statement, so that if urlString starts itms: then it should send the url to safari instead of webview. How would I write the if statement to check if it starts with itms?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation for the `NSString` method `hasPrefix:`.